# Curl to localhost port connection refused when using old version curl

Tags: curl

I am trying to make a curl to a localhost nodejs express server that I have on my machine. The express machine is running and listening on the port (4001), and I disabled the firewall for debug purposes.

On my machine I have php 7.2.13 with curl 7.61.1

But I am trying to use my docker container php 5.6.40 with curl 7.35.0

When I call using php7 and the newer curl, I get a response.

When I call using php5 and the older curl, I get "Connection refused":

```
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4001 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying ::1...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
* Failed to connect to localhost port 4001: Connection refused
* Closing connection 1
```

This is the php code of the curl, which is identical for both:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "4001",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:4001/api/client/set/141b2cab9352c9adb0edf708dab8937e?=",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE =>true,
  CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose,
  CURLOPT_HEADER =>1,  
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_SSLVERSION =>4,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err."<br><br>";
    rewind($verbose);
    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
    echo "Verbose information:<br><pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre><br>";
}
echo "r:$response<br>";
```

I tried telling the express server to listen on all ports, but it didn't work:

```
 server.listen(process.env.HTTP_PORT,'0.0.0.0');
```

I think the issue is only on development, because the curl to the real server is working on production

Is there any way to fix it for php5.6? I can't change now to php7 because the production is still using php5.6.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was not curl version, it was that I the docker container was connected to the host in bridged network mode, so it couldn't use the 'localhost' of the host. To access a service running on the host I need to use the host ip (which I got from 'ipconfig).